# Download hex and decompile it from avr

Tags: c, hex, avr, atmega

I have Orange PI with ubuntu connected to atmega328p through usbasp.
I've developed a program in C, compiled it, translated to hex and uploaded on the atmega, but because of some strange behavior, the file.c is lost.
How can I get my program back from the atmega?

Comment: Good luck. You can dump the flash and get a disassembly, but there's no good way of getting your C file back. Sounds like it's only one file; you're probably better off just rewriting it from scratch.

Comment: C is not Java. Compilation is generally a one-way process, even if you compiled with all the debug options on.

Comment: learn `git` and always have pushed commits to the uplink

Comment: Nope.  Impossible.  Try backing up your stuff next time and consider it a life lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The good news:** It is possible, definitively.

**The bad news:** But it's a lot of work, depending on the size of your application. I did this more than one time with AVR code, written in C, BASCOM, or C++ (Arduino). It takes several hours, for example some 20 hours for a 100-liner in BASCOM.

The approach is:

1. Disassemble the HEX file. Use this output as reference. You might need some options to have all constant data in the output.
2. Start with the best approximation of the source that your memory still holds.
3. Compile, link and convert it into a HEX file, too.
4. Disassemble this HEX file, and compare the output with the reference.
5. Repeat editing your source until both disassemblies are equal.

Notes:

- You need deep understanding about the translation from C into machine code.
- The names of functions and variables can't be reconstructed exactly. These names are gone after compiling and linking.
- Be aware that the order of functions in the resulting code might not depend on their appearance in the source. Most compilers do this, though.
- Be aware that the order of variables in memory might not depend on their appearance in the source, but on their name. Additionally they are commonly not sorted lexically, for example I found GCC using some kind of hashing algorithm. However, members of structs keep their order, because the standard demands that.
- In a first phase, ignore differences of variable placement.
- Try to identify functions of the C library, and ignore them. Especially the `printf()` family draws a lot of other functions with it. When you own code is finished, the library functions will be there, too, most probably.

Final note: If you happen to have the ELF file, use this for disassembling and looking up names. You will be much faster.